# WPF show/hide multiple windows

Tags: wpf

I´m using this current function in WPF for hiding and showing windows.

My process flow is:
From the login screen I go to main menu screen and then from Main menu to other screens, then from all other screens I can either come back to main menu or logout.

The problem I am facing is when I jump from inside screen to Logout it hides main menu screen for first time but when I do that again during current execution, it doesn't collapsed the main menu screen.

```
private void DisplayWindow(Window windowToShow)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().
        Where(w => w.IsVisible).Count(); i++)
    {
        Window windowToHide = Application.Current.Windows[i];
        windowToHide.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
     }
     windowToShow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

This is how I call the function

```
DisplayWindow(_frmDetail);
```

Comment: If you only want to show one window at a time then I suggest you consider a single window app. The mainwindow has anything common in it like a navigation menu. It hosts one usercontrol at a time in a contentcontrol. This would initially be log in. The common pattern for navigation is viewmodel first. Where a dependency property of mainwindowviewmodel is bound to content of that contentcontrol and templated into the different views. LoginView would be a usercontrol and a datatemplate associate it with LoginViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to hide all other windows than `windowToShow`:

```
foreach (Window windowToHide in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>())
{
    if (windowToHide != windowToShow)
        windowToHide.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
windowToShow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: I am getting an error on .Except(windowToShow), cannot convert from system.windows.window to system.collections.generic.ienumerable<system.windows.window>

Comment: When I change it to ```foreach (Window windowToHide in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Except((IEnumerable<Window>)windowToShow))``` still gives error

Comment: @percydeveloper: Right, get rid of `Except`. See my edit.